# Sign an ActiveX control for intranet usage?

Tags: activex

I have created an activex control that will be used **only** for our intranet. Can I somehow sign the control for free if its being used only internally or do I still  need to buy a certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to sign the control with a certificate that all machines on your intranet trust.  This article http://www.top20toolbar.com/misc/codesigncert.htm suggests a method but it involves importing a certificate on every client computer, which may be impractical for you.
If you have an internal certificate server (eg MS Certificate Services) that all machines trust it would make deployment easier.