# How to embed 3rd party DLL on the client side of ASP.NET Forms application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am sorry for very lengthy introduction here but I want to explain my problem in details.

We have a 3rd party dll from one of our vendors that provides Silverlight-based user interface to their data.

We already use that dll in two different projects:

1. IE toolbar button that opens a UI window to that 3rd party data related to the currently displayed data on the webpage (another web application).
2. Windows application (.exe) that is called from another windows application when user pressed a particular key combintion (again passing parameters from that application).

We also have a working ASP.NET (forms) intranet application (in-house developed). Users of that application also want an easy access provided by that DLL. I need a solution for making it possible.

As we have corporate controlled environment we have .NET Framework, Silverlight, the toolbar and executable installed on users' machines and all web applications run in IE.

So far I was able to call the existing exe (that I mentioned in #2) and pass the parameters from my asp.net application as ActiveX (similar to what described here [How to launch an EXE from Web page (asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916925/how-to-launch-an-exe-from-web-page-asp-net)). It works but every time it gives that standard popup "An ActiveX control on this page might be unsafe...".

I also tried to create my own dll that wraps the 3rd party dll and embed it in my asp.net page using `<object>` html tag. It works too but also displays the same popup every time.

Here are my choices (in preference order):

1. Embed the UI provided by the 3rd party dll (possible wrapped in another dll) in existing page of my asp.net application (currently it opens a new window).
2. Call executable with parameters (as I do it now) but without annoying pop-up about ActiveX security.
3. Embed dll using `<object>` tag as a rich client side custom control.

Either way I don't want users to see the popup every time they go to the 3rd party application.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If object tag code ran effortlessly without participation from the user it would be a virus/malware delivery mechanism.

One way is to sign the activex object and then get all your machines to trust it, e.g.

[Sign an ActiveX control for intranet usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030605/sign-an-activex-control-for-intranet-usage)

Comment: Thank you, I will look if I can use it.